# Не работает particle system unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Вообщем при наложении на что бы то ни было элемента particle system все частица квадратные и фиолетовые. Я так понимаю что у них просто нет текстуры. Как это исправить?

[image: Скрин эффекта]
[image: Renderer]

Comment: вкладку Renderer пожалуйста заскриньте скорее всего разгадка там

Comment: Добавил скрин renderer

Comment: это ошибка шейдера...

Comment: И как ипраить то

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это в принципе не ошибка, просто Unity по умолчанию вместо битого шейдера или **отсутствующего** материала ставит шейдер с кислотно-фиолетовым цветом

Comment: Это я понял. Скажите пожалуйста как тогда назначить на него шейдер?

Comment: У вас материала нет, как вам уже сказали. Создайте материал и у него тип укажите Particles-чтототам, и поставьте текстуру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён. Просто добавил материал.

Comment: Вы уж либо полноценно ответьте на вопрос, либо удалите его.